# SQL Compact Edition 3.5 SP 1 - LockTimeOutException - how to debug?

Tags: multithreading, sql-server-ce

Intermittently in our app, we encounter LockTimeoutExceptions being throw from SQL CE. We've recently upgraded to 3.5 SP 1, and a number of them seem to have gone away, but we still do see them occasionally. I'm certain it's a bug in our code (which is multi-threaded) but I haven't been able to pin it down precisely. Does anyone have any good techniques for debugging this problem? The exceptions log like this (there's never a stack trace for these exceptions):

> SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce: default lock timeout property. [ Session id = 6,Thread id = 7856,Process id = 10116,Table name = Product,Conflict type = s lock (x blocks),Resource = DDL ]

Our database is read-heavy, but does seldom writes, and I *think* I've got everything protected where it needs to be.

EDIT: SQL CE already automatically uses NOLOCK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172398(sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that 3.5 SP1 includes new information in the exception that let me pin in down.

> SQL Server Compact timed out waiting for a lock. The default lock time is 2000ms for devices and 5000ms for desktops. The default lock timeout can be increased in the connection string using the ssce: default lock timeout property. [ Session id = 6,Thread id = 7856,Process id = 10116,*Table name = Product*,Conflict type = s lock (x blocks),*Resource = DDL* ]

I was able to identify that it was occuring when were trying to drop an existing table that must have open connections to it.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this page, I discovered another reason why this can occur.  I had created a SqlCeTransaction to wrap various statements, and I accidentally didn't use that transaction on one of the statements.  That was causing my Lock timeout message.